# Problemas com exclusão de arquivos git

Tags: git, github

Recentemente, tive um problema de conflito entre minha branch local impl-springboot4 e a branch remota master. No momento do MERGE via Pull Request, houve conflito onde eu tive de entrar na branch impl-springboot4 para resolver.

O conflito foi no arquivo **UsuarioDTO.java**.

Dentro da branch **impl-springboot4**, fiz **git pull origin master** para atualizá-la afim de resolver o conflito. Entretanto, outros arquivos **com novas versões que vieram da origin master se integraram à minha branch, cerca de 74 arquivos.**

Eu resolvi o conflito no arquivo UsuarioDTO.java, commitei e dei **git push -u origin impl-springboot4**, mas alguns arquivos de versões novas que vieram da origin master e que não continham conflito sumiram do meu projeto. **No meu commit, aparece apenas a correção do arquivo que estava em conflito. Não há nenhuma informação no meu commit de que eu tenha deletado algum arquivo com versão nova vindo da origin master no momento do git pull origin master na minha branch local**. Eu já fiz git pull origin master para recuperar os arquivos que sumiram, mas minha branch não tá mais puxando estes arquivos. Eu me recordo fiz 'git checkout -- .' para todos os arquivos e apenas inclui o arquivo que estava em conflito.

Em 'git diff' dentro do bitbucket da minha branch, aparecem todos os arquivos de versões novas que minha branch recebeu no momento do git pull origin master, com adição, remoção e edição desses arquivos. Os arquivos excluidos não aparecem mais na minha branch, mas eles ainda continuam na origin master.

Já tentei dar git revert HEAD^, git reset no commit para desfazer esse merge commit mas não consigo, dá erro. O meu medo é que quando a pessoa faça o 'merge' via Pull Request, estes arquivos deletados também sejam deletados do repositorio remoto Master, sendo que até onde eu me lembro, eu não excluí nenhum arquivo, mas tudo indica que alguns arquivos foram deletados na minha branch e se isso for pra origin master, pode ser que acabe deletando do repositório remoto também e isso eu não quero que aconteça.

O que devo fazer? Cancelar o pull request e abrir outra branch pra jogar minha implementação ou eu consigo arrumar isso desfazendo esse ultimo commit com adições/edições/exclusoes?

To muito preocupado com isso e perdi umas 5 horas tentando consertar essa situação mas sem sucesso. Agradeço qualquer orientação. obrigado

Comment: Já tive problemas parecidos com esse e consegui resolvê-los da maneira mais simplificada: quando o usuário clona um projeto do GitHub no computador, sempre no diretório em que o usuário inicializa o repositório existe uma pasta oculta chamada .git. Caso esteja usando o shell do linux, experimente apagar a pasta .git que está dentro do projeto e digitar `clear` no terminal. Verá que o `(master)` não irá mais aparecer no seu projeto, daí é só inicializar o repositório e fazer o commit novamente.

Comment: não é recomendado desfazer commits ou até mesmo tentar editá-los, pois como cada commit é uma atualização (versão) do seu projeto, quando se arrisca em tentar alterá-lo correrá sérios riscos em perder todas as atualizações (commits) do seu projeto.

Comment: tanto faz, geralmente o prompt de comando do Windows opera pelo MS-DOS, então recomendo fortemente que utilize o Shell Script do Git Bash para realizar a operação. Como o caso é o repositório do GitHub, pode usar o Git Bash nesse caso.

Comment: Pelo Git Bash, você vai até a pasta onde está o seu repositório clonado, deleta a pasta `.git` dá um `clear` no terminal para limpar o console. Quando o `(master)` aparece, significa que aquele projeto não é mais um repositório, então é só digitar `git init && git add . && git commit "realizando o commit novamente" && git remote add origin "<URL do repositorio>" && git push -u origin master`. Desculpe pelo coringa `&&`, não quero explicar em detalhes para que ele serve, mas se for do seu interesse deixo aqui o link para estudo:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command

Comment: Muito interessante sua explicação. Confesso que não me sinto seguro usando estes comandos no git, uso apenas o habitual (push, pull, merge, commit, add, checkout --...). Eu pensei em uma outra alternativa, veja se é possível:

Pensei em fazer GIT CHECKOUT MASTER, copiar todos os arquivos e jogar pra uma pasta qualquer que não seja repositório local, depois GIT CHECKOUT IMPL_SPRINGBOOT4 e colar os arquivos copiados anteriormente do repositorio da master. O git vai verificar automaticamente os arquivos que são iguais, os arquivos novos e os arquivos com versão atualizada. Então, comitar.

Comment: faça a alternativa que achar melhor para vc, muitas das vezes é melhor utilizar os comandos habituais que vc conhece bem do que se arriscar em outros que são vistos pela internet e que não são muitos comuns de se utilizar, a não ser que tenha casos específicos que precise utilizar esses outros caminhos, mas aconselho a seguir sempre os mais habituais como vc mencionou.

Comment: É possível trabalhar de várias formas com o Git Hub, mas a ideia é ter em mente que sempre quando se fala de commit refere-se a versões do seu projeto atual e caso queira reverter algum commit na própria plataforma tem a opção de vc clicar no commit que deseja atualizar para o estado atual de seu projeto, baixar todos os arquivos dele e substituí-los no diretório atual de seu projeto e commitá-los novamente.

Comment: Analisando a situação, eu acredito que copiar os arquivos da master como mencionei anteriormente e colar dentro da branch impl_springboot4 é o caminho mais fácil sem precisar utilizar comandos de git especificos. E o grande problema é que o commit já foi dado push a 'origin impl_springboot4', e pelo o que eu pesquisei não é possível desfazer esse commit pois foi já foi dado push, além de eu ter tentado fazer 'git revert HEAD^' mas o git não permitiu, e poderia dar problema. Diante disso, eu vejo que a solução seria essa que descrevi e pretendo fazer hoje. Voce acha que irá resolver o problema?

Comment: Sim, é só testar e ver